# adjoint representation completely reducible

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a Lie algebra. Suppose that adjoint representation of $\mathcal{A}$ is completely reducible (or semisimple). Show that $\mathcal{A}$ can be written as a direct sum of semisimple Lie algebra and abelian Lie algebra.

I know an answer supposing that $\mathcal{A}$ is finite-dimensional Lie algebra.  Is there any answer that does not depend on the dimension of algebra?

Thanks!!!